# Is it possible for a binary integer operation that results in an overflow to overwrite adjacent memory?

Tags: memory-leaks, theory, overflow, cpu-architecture

This question is not about any error I'm currently seeing, it's more about theory and getting educated on the variations in HW architecture design and implementation.

---

**Scenario 1:** Assuming a 16-bit processor with 16-bit registers, 16-bit addressing, and sizeof(int) = 16 bits:

```
unsigned int a, b, c, d;
a=0xFFFF;
b=0xFFFF;
c=a+b;
```

Is it possible for the memory location next to `c` to be overwritten? 
 (In this case I would expect that an overflow flag would be raised during the *add* operation, and `c` either remain unchanged or be filled with undefined data.)

---

**Scenario 2:** Assuming a 32-bit processor with 32-bit registers, 32-bit addressing, sizeof(int) = 32 bits, and sizeof(short int)=16 bits:

```
unsigned int a, b;
unsigned short int c, d;
a=0xFFFF;
b=0xFFFF;
c=a+b;
```

Is it possible for the memory location next to `c` to be overwritten? 
(I would expect that no overflow flag be raised during the add operation, but whether or not a memory access or overflow flag be raised during the assignment operation would depend on the actual design and implementation of the HW. If `d` was located in the upper 16 bits of the same 32-bit address location (probably not even possible with 32-bit addressing), it might be overwritten.)

---

**Scenario 3:** Assuming a 32-bit processor with 32-bit registers, **16**-bit addressing, sizeof(int) = 32 bits, and sizeof(short int)=16 bits:

```
unsigned int a, b;
unsigned short int c, d;
a=0xFFFF;
b=0xFFFF;
c=a+b;
```

Is it possible for the memory location next to `c` to be overwritten? 
(I would expect some overflow flag or memory violation flag to be raised during the type conversion and assignment operation.)

---

**Scenario 4:** Assuming a 32-bit processor with 32-bit registers, 32-bit addressing, and sizeof(int) = 32 bits:

```
unsigned int a, b;
struct {
    unsigned int c:16;
    unsigned int d:16;
} e;
a=0xFFFF;
b=0xFFFF;
e.c=a+b;
```

Is it possible for the memory location next to `c`, namely `d`, to be overwritten? (In this case, since `c` and `d` are expected to reside in the same 32-bit address and both are technically 32-bit integers, it's conceivable that no overflow flags be raised during addition or assignment, and `d` could be affected.)

---

I have not tried to test this on actual hardware because my question is more about theory and possible variations in design and implementation. Any insight would be appreciated.

- Is it possible for a binary integer operation that results in an overflow to overwrite adjacent memory?
- Are there currently any HW implementations that suffer from similar memory overwrite problems, or have there been systems in the past that had this problem?
- What devices do typical processors use to guard against neighboring memory from being overwritten by arithmetic and assignment operations?

Comment: Isn't this more about how a specific language's implementation (looks like C) handles assignment of integers to variables of a smaller integral type?

Comment: I'd say the answer is "no, for any reasonable architecture and programming language" - but see [The Story of Mel](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~elb/folklore/mel.html) for an entertaining account of what might happen on old architectures where it _is_ possible... :-)

Comment: @delnan:  Yes, it's possible that this question is heavily language dependent, but since all languages have to be converted to machine code before being run there is a commonality to them all at the HW level.  The examples use a C-like syntax since I believe that to be most accessible to the majority of SO readers. An assembly-like syntax might have been better suited to the questions but might not have helped get my point across... ...then again, constructing this in machine code might just provide me with the 'Aha!' insight I'm looking for.

Comment: But all languages, even C, define their own set of rules concerning this. Some might specify very rigrid truncation rules, others might leave it undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addition operation is processed inside the processor afaik, so whatever you do, the add operation will be done inside the CPU (in the ALU more precisely)
The overflow register would be set in case of overflow, and the result will still be in  the register, and then copied back to your memory location without risk of corrupting adjacent memory.
This is how the code would (sort of) be translated in asm:

```
mov ax, ptr [memory location of a]
mov bx, ptr [memory location of b]
add ax,bx
mov ptr [memory location of c], ax
```

so as you can see, c would only hold what was in ax (which is of a known and fixed size) no matter if an overflow occurred or not

Comment: That's the case for all reasonably modern processors (i.e., less than 40 years old) I know about.  That's not necessarily true of all possible processors (although C and C++ define unsigned integer overflow so that no extra overwriting is possible).

Comment: do you know processors that don't do it this way? I've never seen any, although I've never seen any more than 30 years old, that was long before I was born ;-)

Answer (score 4):

None of your 1,2,3,4 will result in any memory corruption, or writing "past" the storage for the integer location you are performing arithmetic on. C specifies what should happen on an overflow of unsigned integers. This is assuming the compiler produces the code it's supposed to. Nothing will guard you acainst a buggy compiler that generates code which copies 4 bytes into a 2 byte variable.

Here's what C99 (6.2.5) says:

"A computation involving unsigned operands can never overﬂow,
because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
represented by the resulting type."

So, it's well defined what will happen when you try to "overflow" an unsigned integer.

Now, if your integers had been signed integers, it is an other story. According to C, overflowing a signed integer results in undefined behavior. And undefined behavior means anything, including memory corruption, could occur. I have not yet seen a C compiler that would corrupt anything regarding overflowing an integer though.

> What devices do typical processors use to guard against neighboring memory from being overwritten by arithmetic and assignment operations?

There's no guards against neighboring memory regarding assignment and arithmetic operations. The processor simply executes the machine code instructions given to it (And if those instructions overwrites memory it was not suppoed to do as expressed in a higher level language, the processor does not care).

At a slightly different level, the CPU might issue [traps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_%28computing%29) if it cannot carry out the operation(e.g. the operation specified memory location that does not exist), or tries to do some illegal operation (e.g. division by zero, or encounters an op code the processor does not understand, or tries to do unaligned access to data).

Answer (score 1):

In C, the behavior of overflows with unsigned types is well-defined.  Any implementation in which overflow causes any result other than what the standard predicts is non-compliant.

The behavior of overflows with signed types is undefined.  While the most common effects of an overflow would either be the assignment of some erroneous value or an outright crash, nothing in the C standard guarantees that the processor won't trigger an overflow fault in a way that the compiled code tries to recover from, but which for some reason trashes the contents of a stack variable or a register.  It's also possible that an overflow could cause a flag to get set in a way that code doesn't expect, and that such a flag might cause erroneous behavior on future computations.

Other languages may have different semantics for what happens when an overflow occurs.

note: I've seen processors which trap on overflow, processors where unexpected traps that happen at the same time as an external interrupt may cause data corruption, and processors where an unexpected unsigned overflow could cause a succeeding computation to be off by one.  I don't know of any where a signed overflow would latch a flag that would interfere with subsequent calculations, but some DSP's have interesting overflow behaviors, so I wouldn't be surprised if one exists.